# Rhino Mocks assert method is called once

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, objectfactory

I have a method that I am testing using Rhino Mocks.  When i test this method by itself, it passes, but when multiple methods are being tested, it fails.  I assume this is because I am not destroying something correctly.  Below is my setup code for creating my ObjectFactory.

```
public void Setup()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<ISecurityManager>().Use<SecurityManager>();
            x.For<IManager>().Use<Manager>();
            x.For<IWorkflowManager>().Use<WorkflowManager>();
        });
    }
```

Here is an example of one of the unit tests.

```
    var mockIWorkflowManager = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IWorkflowManager>();
    mockIWorkflowManager.Stub(d => d.SendCompletedEmailWithComments(Arg<WorkOrder>.Is.Anything, Arg<string>.Is.Anything));
    ObjectFactory.Inject(typeof(IWorkflowManager), mockIWorkflowManager);

    SubmitAction action = new SubmitAction();
    action.SendNotifyEmail("toUser", new WorkOrder(), "currentUser", new StepAction { Name = "with comments" });

    mockIWorkflowManager.AssertWasCalled(x => x.SendCompletedEmailWithComments(Arg<WorkOrder>.Is.Anything, Arg<string>.Matches(y => y == "toUser")));
    mockIWorkflowManager.AssertWasNotCalled(x => x.SendNotifyEmail(Arg<string>.Is.Anything, Arg<WorkOrder>.Is.Anything, Arg<string>.Is.Anything));
```

the other tests are similar, just changing return values to affect logic path.  If I run them one at a time, they all pass, but if I run them all at once, they all fail.

Comment: Can you also show the code that you're trying to test?

Comment: Not possible to show code that this is testing.

Comment: Why would you stub a method if you aren't also providing a return value for it?
I see you're injecting the workflow manager...I presume the SubmitAction is using it, but how? If it were injected in the constructor you could've simply passed it in as a parameter, but it's clear that's not the case.